# Java Triangular Numbers Calculator

Tags: java

I am having odd errors with my triangular numbers generator, bear in mind i am very new to programming.
At a certain point in the program the numbers glitch out and some become minus numbers (it is worth noting that the numbers don't just have a - in front of them they are actually glitched out!)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TriangularNumbers {
       @SuppressWarnings("resource")
       public static void main(String args[]) {
            int tnumber = 1;
            int amount = 2;     
            System.out.println("Welcome to the triangular numbers         calculator!");
            System.out.println("Type in the amount of triangular numbers to be generated!");
            Scanner reps = new Scanner(System.in);
            int repeats = reps.nextInt();
            int i = 0;
            while (i < repeats) {
                i = i + 1;
                System.out.println(i + ". " + tnumber);
                tnumber = tnumber + amount;
                amount = (amount + 1);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you add your output?

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: The whole lot or just an exert from the odd bit?

Comment: A Java int has 32 bits. It can store numbers up to Integer.MAX_VALUE. When it overflows it counts from the smallest negative number onwards. Use long or BigInteger to store bigger numbers

Comment: Do you know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

if you look up triangular numbers online you can easily spot (i did on wikipedia) that the amount of corners found in triangular number n, can be given by the math type T(n) = n(n+1)2

therefor to calculate it you could do something like that (your code, minor changes)

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
        long tnumber;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the triangular numbers calculator!");
        System.out.println("Type in the amount of triangular numbers to be generated!");

        Scanner reps = new Scanner(System.in);
        int repeats = reps.nextInt();
        int i = 1;

        while (i <= repeats) {
            tnumber = i(i+1)/2;
            System.out.println(i + ". " + tnumber);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

This code gives your tnumber variable greater max values and it doesn't require the use of the amount variable.

I really miss the point of using Java for something like that tho, u should aim for more object-oriented code while using java.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing, from the looks of it, was answered in the comments by [Erwin Bolwidt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981744/erwin-bolwidt) called *Integer Overflow*. Since everything is stored in Binary on computers, certain data types can only hold so much data. In Java the `int` primitive is 32 bits, which gives us a max value of `2147483647` or `2^(31)-1`.

This can be solved using the `long` primitive datatype, although it does use more resources in memory (since it can store more data). The `long` is a 64-bit data type which gives a maximum number of `9223372036854775807` or `2^(63)-1`.

Source: [Oracle Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful!

Comment: Would I just change int to long, because I did that and now I get this:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "10000000000"
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2123)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at TriangularNumbers.main(TriangularNumbers.java:11)

Comment: The same issue is occurring. The number you input is larger than the `Integer` can hold. Change the data type of `repeats` and `i` to `long` and change `reps.nextInt()` to `reps.nextLong()`.

Comment: I'm glad this answer was helpful. If you feel this was the best answer, please select it as such. This increases the possibility of your future questions being answered as well as credits me for answering the question. I'd wait 12 hours after the question was posted to assure no better answers are posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner um=new Scanner(System.in);

    int y,x=0;
    System.out.print("Enter Number to find Triangular Number: ");
    int a=um.nextInt();
    for ( ; x < a; x++) {
        y= x*(x+1)/2;
        System.out.println("This is a Triangular Num: "+y);
    }   
}
```

Comment: you should add some explanation to what you are doing to fix the code. This will also allow you to properly format it.

Answer (score 0):

```
package domain;

public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n =1;

    while(n<=45){
        System.out.println(n*3);
        n++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include context to your source code in order to clarify your response. 
Please check the documentation [on how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)